Comparing GLMs with different fitted distributions
I have a scenario where I need to compare some generalized liner models (with same link function, target variable, but not necessarily nested) with k fold cross validation, using a cost function to compare "closeness" of predicted values with actual data in the hold out set. As far as I understand, the metric which gives this measure is Deviance in GLM paradigm since unlike OLS, variance is not assumed constant. However, as I could see in texts, deviance seems to be a function of underlying distribution being fit and so its functional(mathematical) form can vary from one distribution to another.
So will I be correct in saying that deviance (as a loss function) can not be used to compare "closeness of actual data vs predicted values" from models with different fitted distributions (e.g. m1 - Gamma, m2 - Inverse Gaussian)? If yes, what would be the preferred metric (loss function) to use in such cases?
